# Should I always stick to useState's naming convention

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I understand that normally we would have something like this
`const [x,setX] = useState(initialValue)`

But I am wondering if this is a hard-and-fast rule. For example, if I have a state, which is a boolean, to indicate whether a button is disabled or enabled. Is it bad if I write something like this

`const [buttonEnabled, enableButton] = useState(false)`

If it is indeed not good, what are some proper names for this state given the purpose of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not hard-and-fast rule.

But it is just a suggestion. Personally, seeing `set` as prefix to a variable 'x' helps me to understand this variable is responsible for updating 'x'.

In case of Boolean variables I prefer to use `is`, `has`, `will`, etc prefix. According to your example, I would use,

```
const [isButtonEnabled, setIsButtonEnabled] = useState(false)
```

Again, it is not a rule, but just a convention to understand the data type and the purpose of the variable as easily possible.

Answer (score 3):

Since useState in this format is just destructuring an array, you can name it whatever you'd like. However, the name `enableButton` with a boolean value would make me think this is a function that is setting the state value to "true" when called. `set` is a generic verb often used for being able to pass whatever value you'd like so it's a nice code usage hint.

In the end it just boils down to being able to be easily read and understood by future you, and other developers.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Your answer totally makes sense. `enableButton` means that we are only setting it to be `true`. but if I have a checkbox or toggle, can I name the them as `const [XEnabled, checkX] = useState(false)`  if it is a checkbox or `const [XEnabled, toggleX] = useState(false)`  if it is a toggle?

Comment: 'toggle' would make me think it's going to flip from whatever the current value is to the opposite. You could create wrapper functions for this kind of use if you'd like to pass/use a function like that. `const toggleX = () => setX(x => !x)`, or `const checkX = () => setX(true)`